# Laravel5: How to work with the timestamp field in migration

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im trying to put a table via migration and here is what im stuck at:

I need the following:

```
$table->timestamps('added_on');
```

and NOT the `created_at` and `updated_at` which are forced into the table even though I didnt mention them in the schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `timestamps()` method is adding the *created_at* and *updated_at* columns. What you need is `timestamp()` (without the **s**) which accepts as an argument a timestamp column name.

`$table->timestamp('added_on');`

Answer (score 0):

To add a Unique Timestamp of your own making; all you need do is call the `$table->timestamp()`Method passing it your `field_name`: in your case `added_on`. So, now; assuming you have a Migration called "TestTable". Here below would be what your Migration File may look like:

```
<?php


    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class TestTable extends Migration {


        public function up() {
            // Create table for storing roles
            Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('field_1')->unique();
                $table->string('field_2');
                $table->string('field_3');

                // THE COMMENTED LINE BELOW ADDS THE 
                // "created_at" & "updated_at" FIELDS IN DB
                // $table->timestamps();        //<== ADDS GENERIC TIMESTAMPS

                // NOW TO ADD YOUR OWN UNIQUE DATE-BASED/TIMESTAMP FIELD,
                // ALL YOU NEED DO IS:::
                $table->timestamp("added_on");  //<== ADD YOUR DATE/TIME FIELD

            });
        }
    }
```